# Can you write a conditional which tests against image dimensions in Assets?

Tags: assets, conditionals, file-uploads

Using Assets, can I write a conditional which tests against the dimensions of an image? So as an example if an image height is >= 200px add this class, < 200px add that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is the easiest thing in the world, and I'm a lazy lazy boy for asking before reading the documentation:

`{assets_field}
    {if '{width'} >= '200px'}
        <img class="big-fella">
    {if:else}
        <img class=""little-lad">
    {/if}
{/assets_field}`